# Jupyter notebook cannot access local files (e.g. <img src="..."...)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've downloaded some Jupyter notebooks and support files from a course I recently took, and I am trying to run them locally. The Notebook runs, but it can't find any of the referenced support files. For example:

```html
<img src="nb_images/driveai.png" style="width:100px;height:100;">
```

This just generates a generic image icon in the notebook. I googled this and tried many things, but nothing seems to work. I've tried it through Anaconda, directly from Python, starting the notebook in the source directory, etc. I am running this in a Windows 10 environment. Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: I would expect the images to be included in a folder (nb_images) within the download

Comment: Do you have `nb_images/driveai.png` in your folder?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out earlier today. The tar command I used to grab files from the Coursera directory did not handle symbolic links properly. The correct command to use is "!tar chvfz notebook.tar.gz". Some of the files had only a link to the actual images or data file in it. Key word is "some" - of course the local files I opened to see what was going on were fine, but many were not. What fooled me was that the files names were there, but the content was bogus. So figured it had to be a path problem of some kind - wrong!